# Java CommandLine Interface implementation

Tags: java, object-oriented

I write a lot of mini apps. Each app has its own `InputHandler` for input from the keyboard. It's time to make a lib for that purpose - a `CommandLineInterface`.

NOTE: there exists a [follow up Question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/214399/followup-commandlineinterpreter-commandlineinteraction) here

Can you review my code on

- Design
- OOP
- Clean Code
- Naming (my bad englisch leads to bad naming)

### Interface CommandLineInterpreter

Any class that implements this interface can use the `CommandLineInterface`. `M` is the application, which implements the `CommandLineInterpreter`

```
public interface CommandLineInterpreter<M> { 
    Set<Command<M>> getCommands();
    Response executeCommand(String identifier, List<String> parameter);
}
```

### Class Command

the `Command` is responsible to map the command typed via CLI into an action (method-call) on your app. To execute the command the Class is generic on `M` (which is your app) so you can call these app-specific methods.

```
public abstract class Command<M> {

    private final String identifier;

    public Command(String identifier) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
    }

    public abstract Response execute(M invoked, List<String> parameter);

    public String getIdentifier() {
        return identifier;
    }

    public boolean isIdentifier(String ident) {
        return identifier.equals(ident);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Command command = (Command) o;
        return Objects.equals(identifier, command.identifier);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(identifier);
    } 
}
```

### Class Response

Provides information if the execution of an command was successful or not.

```
public class Response {
    private final String message;
    private final String details;
    private final Type type;

    private Response(Type type, String message, String details) {
        this.type = type;
        this.message = message;
        this.details = details;
    }

    public static Response fail(String message) {
        return fail(message, "");
    }

    public static Response fail(String message, String details) {
        return response(Type.FAILURE, message, details);
    }

    private static Response response(Type type, String message, String details) {
        return new Response(type, message, details);
    }

    public static Response success() {
        return success("ok", "");
    }

    public static Response success(String message) {
        return success(message, "");
    }

    public static Response success(String message, String details) {
        return response(Type.SUCCESS, message, details);
    }

    public boolean failed() {
        return type == Type.FAILURE;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return type.toString() + ":" + message + (details.isEmpty() ? "" : " 
Details: " + details);
    }

    private enum Type {SUCCESS, FAILURE}
```

### Class CommandLineInterface

This class handles the user input from the command line. It is itself a `CommandLineInterpreter` and offers two basic commands: `help` and `exit`.

```
public class CommandLineInterface implements CommandLineInterpreter<CommandLineInterface> {

    private static final String COMMAND_SEPARATOR = " ";
    private final CommandLineInterpreter cli; 
    private final InputStream input;
    private final PrintStream output;
    private boolean isRunning = true;

    public CommandLineInterface(CommandLineInterpreter<?> cli, InputStream input, PrintStream output) {
        if (cli == null || hasPredefinedCommands(cli.getCommands())) {
            throw new RuntimeException("CommandLineInterpreter interface of " + cli + " is not properly implemented");
        }
        this.cli = cli;
        this.input = input;
        this.output = output;
    }

    private boolean hasPredefinedCommands(Set<? extends Command<?>> commands) {
        return !Collections.disjoint(commands, getCommands());
    }

    public void start() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);
        showHelp();
        while (isRunning) {
            output.print("$>");
            String command = scanner.nextLine();
            List<String> line = Arrays.asList(command.split(COMMAND_SEPARATOR));
            String identifier = line.get(0);
            List<String> parameters = line.subList(1, line.size());
            if (isExecutableCommand(identifier)) {
                Response response = executeCommand(identifier, parameters);
                if (response.failed()) {
                    showResponse(response);
                }
            } else {
                showHelp();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isExecutableCommand(String identifier) {
        for (Command cmd : getAllCommands()) {
            if (cmd.isIdentifier(identifier)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void showHelp() {
        Set<Command<?>> commands = getAllCommands();
        output.println("help - these commands are available:");
        commands.forEach(c -> output.printf(" - %s\n", c.getIdentifier()));
    }

    private void showResponse(Response response) {
        output.println(response);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Command<CommandLineInterface>> getCommands() {
        Set<Command<CommandLineInterface>> cliCommands = new HashSet<>();
        cliCommands.add(new Command<CommandLineInterface>("exit") {
            @Override
            public Response execute(CommandLineInterface commandLineInterface, List<String> parameter) {
                isRunning = false;
                return Response.success();
            }
        });
        cliCommands.add(new Command<CommandLineInterface>("help") {
            @Override
            public Response execute(CommandLineInterface commandLineInterface, List<String> parameter) {
                showHelp();
                return Response.success();
            }
        });
        return cliCommands;
    }

    private Set<Command<?>> getAllCommands() {
        Set<Command<?>> commands = mapCommands(cli.getCommands());
        commands.addAll(getCommands());
        return commands;
    }

    private Set<Command<?>> mapCommands(Set commands) {
        Set<Command<?>> mappedCommands = new HashSet<>();
        for (Object o : commands) mapCommand(o).ifPresent(mappedCommands::add);
        return mappedCommands;
    }

    private Optional<Command<?>> mapCommand(Object o) {
        return (o instanceof Command<?>) ? Optional.of((Command<?>) o) : Optional.empty();
    }

    @Override
    public Response executeCommand(String identifier, List<String> parameter) {
        Optional<Command<CommandLineInterface>> cmd = getCommands().stream().filter(command -> command.isIdentifier(identifier)).findAny();
        if (cmd.isPresent()) {
            return cmd.get().execute(this, parameter);
        } else {
            return cli.executeCommand(identifier, parameter);
        }
    }

}
```

### Example

If you have implemented the interfaces properly you should have easy to use CLI support for your apps:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExampleApplication app = new ExampleApplication();//implements CommandLineInterpreter
    CommandLineInterface commandLineInterface = new CommandLineInterface(app, System.in, System.out);
    commandLineInterface.start();
}
```

### Output

this is an example output from an example app that does not much...

```
help - these commands are available:
 - exampleCommand
 - help
 - exit
$>help
help - these commands are available:
 - exampleCommand
 - help
 - exit
$>exampleCommand p1 p2 p3
i could do some actual work now if i were not a mere example, parameter [p1, p2, p3]
$>exit

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Generics

> To execute the command the Class is generic on M (which is your app)
>
> ```java
> public abstract class Command<M> {
>    // ..
>    public abstract Response execute(M invoked, List<String> parameter);
>    // ..
> ```

\$ \$

> `M` is the application, which implements the `CommandLineInterpreter`
>
> ```java
> public interface CommandLineInterpreter<M> { 
>    Set<Command<M>> getCommands();
>    Response executeCommand(String identifier, List<String> parameter);
> }
> ```

Both quotes are wrong, because `M` would allow every reference type like  `Integer` or `CustomClassXY`.

To implement it like in the quote described that `M` can only be `CommandLineInterface` you do not need generics..

```java
abstract class Command {
    // ..
     public abstract Response execute(CommandLineInterface invoked, List<String> parameter);
    // ..
}

interface CommandLineInterpreter {
    Set<Command> getCommands();
    Response executeCommand(String identifier, List<String> parameter);
}
```

After that we can change the redundant methods to map the `Command`s inside a `Set`

> ```java
> private Set<Command<?>> getAllCommands() {
>    Set<Command<?>> commands = mapCommands(cli.getCommands());
>    commands.addAll(getCommands());
>    return commands;
> }
>
> private Set<Command<?>> mapCommands(Set commands) {
>   Set<Command<?>> mappedCommands = new HashSet<>();
>   for (Object o : commands) mapCommand(o).ifPresent(mappedCommands::add);
>   return mappedCommands;
> }
>
> private Optional<Command<?>> mapCommand(Object o) {
>    return (o instanceof Command<?>) ? Optional.of((Command<?>) o) : Optional.empty();
> }
> ```

Can know look like

```java
private Set<Command> getAllCommands() {
    Set<Command> commands = cli.getCommands();
    commands.addAll(getCommands());
    return commands;
}
```

You can read more about [Generics in Effective Java from Joshua Bloch](https://the-eye.eu/public/Books/IT%20Various/Effective%20Java%2C%202nd%20Edition.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A689%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C-57%2C644%2C1%5D).

## A More Suitable Data Structure

> ```java
> // in commandLineInterface.executeCommand
> Optional<Command<CommandLineInterface>> cmd = getCommands().stream()
>                                                            .filter(command -> command.isIdentifier(identifier))
>                                                            .findAny();
> ```

The task of `executeCommand` is to find only *one* `Command` from `getCommands`. The method signature of `getCommands` is

> ```java
> Set<Command<CommandLineInterface>> getCommands()
> ```

A [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) only provides its content through an `Iterator`, so we have to iterate all elements to get the element we want with a time complexity of \$O(n)\$

A [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) in the form of `Map<Indentifier, Command>` is equivalent to a `Set` but with the benefit that we can access a element through the `get`-method in \$O(1)\$.

```java
Optional<Command<CommandLineInterface>> cmd = Optional.ofNullable(getCommands().get(identifier));
```

---

## [Feature Envy](http://wiki.c2.com/?FeatureEnvySmell)

> The whole point of objects is that they are a technique to package data with the processes used on that data. A classic [code] smell is a method that seems more interested in a class other than the one it is in. The most common focus of the envy is the data.

### In Method `hasPredefinedCommands`

When we take a look into the constructor of `CommandLineInterface`, we can find a method `hasPredefinedCommands`.

> ```java
> public CommandLineInterface(CommandLineInterpreter<?> cli, InputStream input, PrintStream output) {
>    if (cli == null || hasPredefinedCommands(cli.getCommands()))
> ```

Since the method gets only used at one place and is private we know that the argument `commands` will always be the commands of a `CommandLineInterpreter`.

> ```java
> private boolean hasPredefinedCommands(Set<? extends Command<?>> commands) {
>    return !Collections.disjoint(commands, getCommands());
> }
> ```

This method should be renamed to `contains` and moved into `CommandLineInterpreter`.

```java
public CommandLineInterface(CommandLineInterpreter<?> cli, InputStream input, PrintStream output) {
    if (cli == null || cli.contains(getCommands())
```

## Responsibilities Of `CommandLineInterface`

You described the `CommandLineInterface` with

> This class handles the user input from the command line. It is itself a CommandLineInterpreter **and** offers two basic commands: help and exit.

The tagged **and** in the quote shows that the `CommandLineInterface` has two responsibilities:

- handles the user input
- offers two basic commands

### Choose a Different Name Like CommandLineInteraction

The name `CommandLineInterface` is so abstract, that it could be everything and from a programmer perspective I would thing that this is an interface and not a class.. Maybe the responsibilities for this class makes more sense, if we change the name to `ComandLineInteraction`.

With this name I associate thinks the already existing method `start` and but also thinks like `stop`, `clean`, `isRunning` and so on..

### Let's Remove the Second Responsibility

First we need to check the reason, why it currently is in `CommandLineInterface`. In the method `CommandLineInterface.getCommands`:

> ```java
> public Set<Command<CommandLineInterface>> getCommands() {
>  // ..
>  cliCommands.add(new Command<CommandLineInterface>("exit") {
>    @Override
>    public Response execute(CommandLineInterface commandLineInterface, >List<String> parameter) {
>      isRunning = false;
>      return Response.success();
>    }
>  });
>  // ..
> }
> ```

The reason is the statement `isRunning = false`, because `isRunning` is a private variable of `CommandLineInterface` and you can only access it inside it.

You already provide a method `start` and we could create a method `stop` too. After that the creation of the commands does no longer need to be in `CommandLineInterface`.

#### The Method `stop`

> ```java
> public void stop() {
>     isRunning = false;
> }
> ```

The method `showHelp` should be public

#### Inject Default Commands through the Contractor

```java
public CommandLineInteractions(..., Map<String, Command> default) {
    // ...
    this.commands = default;
}
```

From the outside it now looks like

```java
Map<String, Command<>> defaults  = new HashMap<>();
defaults.put("exit", 
             new Command("exit") {
                 @Override
                 public Response execute(CommandLineInterface commandLineInterface, List<String> parameter) {
                     commandLineInterface.stop();
                     return commandLineInterface.isRunning() 
                         ? Response.fail("App is still running")
                         : Response.success();
             }
});
CommandLineInterface app = new Command(..., defaults);
```

---

## To The Comments

> ok about the proper data type (map instead of set) - i want to free the app of creating a redundant data type (identifier, Command) since the command already provides a method getIdentifier()... so any CommandLineInterpreter has to only return the commands that are availible. the amount of commands is rather short, i don't expect more than a dozends commands to be availible so i tend to CleanCode rule *don't optimze* , see https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-1-red/#Beware_of_Optimizations

From the link you provide:

> Understandability of code hast always priority. Optimized code pretty often is all but well readable.

I think the optimization rule doesn't apply to change the `Set` to an `Map`, since the `Map` is the more readable and intuitive way of getting a `Command` by its name.

> i want to free the app of creating a redundant data type (identifier, Command) since the command already provides a method getIdentifier()...

The *identifier* can still be the string you used before. So it is not really redundant.

When we philosophize a little bit: *Does a command need an identifier (name) by it self?*

The `Map`-solution would make the *identifier* in the command useless and more flexable:
Imagine you use your tool on work and you have a new Spanish employee with low (in your case German) or English skills. Your tool currently only works in german/english and the new employee don't know how to use it.
With `Set` solution you need to make a new Command, witch is doing the same only with a new identifier, but with the `Map` solution you put in the reference of the same command but with a different key.

### Create a [First Class Collection](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/luontola/tdd-2009/ext/ObjectCalisthenics.pdf)

> i want to free the app

What is a First Class Collection:

> Any class that contains a collection should contain no other member variables. Each collection gets wrapped in its own class, so now behaviors related to the collection have a home.

When you know want to switch from a `Set` to a `Map` or what ever data-type you need to change at sooo *many* places. But with a FCC you need *only* to change inside the FCC.

The FCC would define all the methods you need like `get` and `contains` and the outer world doesn't care if you are using inside it a `Set` or a `Map` - or short : [data encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)).

Comment: Hello @Roman i had really problems with generics, i always get "unchecked" warnings - that's why i had so much work around these commands... honestly i have some lacks on generics, which leads into bloated code... (this comment is for the check for instance part)

Comment: About `Responsibilities Of CommandLineInterpreter` i was thinking the same. you could (as intented) have a private CommandLineInterpreter who's responsible for the commands, that would make the `CommandLineInterface` lighter - as well as it would lead to making `stop` as a public method (mentioned before)

Comment: Yes, this makes a lot of sense to me :]

Comment: it's weird, i got this idea finally after i posted my code - i wonder, why i never do realize that earlier ....

Comment: aahhhh i did the generics wrong all over!! thank you for pointing that out - this makes all more clear now!!

Comment: ok about the proper data type (map instead of set) - i want to free the app of creating a redundant data type (identifier, Command) since the command already provides a method getIdentifier()... so any CommandLineInterpreter has to only return the commands that are availible. the amount of commands is rather short, i don't expect more than a dozends commands to be availible so i tend to CleanCode rule **don't optimze** , see https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-1-red/#Beware_of_Optimizations

Comment: even it were hundres of commands, the user input (via command line) is always slower

Comment: I've already updated parts of the git repository at https://github.com/martinFrank/commandLineInterface

Comment: i wished i could upvote once more =) this really helped very much and i already made **major** changes