# FollowUp CommandLineInterpreter (CommandLineInteraction)

Tags: java, object-oriented

I wrote an [command line interpreter (CLI) in Java and got some real helpful hints](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/214300/java-commandline-interface-implementation/214356?noredirect=1#comment414546_214356) on how to improve.

The cli is responsible to pick up the users input (via keyboard aka command line) into any app that implements the `CommandLineInterpreter`.

The app itself offers commands to the CLI that can be executed. If the user types in a proper command the CLI executes that command on the app.

Note: i changes the name from `CommandLineInterface` into `CommandLineInteraction` to prevent an misinterpreting naiming (i wished i could speak english)

Can you review this code on

- Design
- Clean code
- OO
- Naming (my bad englisch leads to bad naming)
- i'm not sure if i have too much aggregation and hard coupling here
- how do i test this application?

### class Command

any command must subclass from this command so the CLI can execute the command when typed in. The command itself is now responsible to call the right methods on it's `Application`

```
public abstract class Command<Application> {

    private final String identifier;
    private final Application application;

    public Command(Application application, String identifier) {
        this.application = application;
        this.identifier = identifier;
    }

    public Application getApplication() {
        return application;
    }

    public abstract Response execute(List<String> parameter);

    public String getIdentifier() {
        return identifier;
    }

    public boolean isIdentifier(String ident) {
        return identifier.equals(ident);
    }

    //lr'dr 
    //this class overrides equals and hashCode on sole parameter "identifier"

}
```

### class CommandLineInteraction

this class is responsible to take the user input, find the correspondig command and execute it finally... (yes sounds like too much responsibility for one class but it *could be rephrased* as `handleInput`)

```
public class CommandLineInteraction implements CommandLineInterpreter {

    private static final String COMMAND_SEPARATOR = " ";
    private static final String COMMAND_PROMPT = "$>";
    private final CommandLineInterpreter cli;
    private final CommandLineInteractionInterpreter commandLineInteractionInterpreter;
    private final InputStream input;
    private final PrintStream output;
    private boolean isRunning = true;

    public CommandLineInteraction(CommandLineInterpreter cli, InputStream input, PrintStream output) {
        commandLineInteractionInterpreter = new CommandLineInteractionInterpreter(this);
        if (cli == null || commandLineInteractionInterpreter.hasCommandInCommon(cli)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("CommandLineInterpreter interface of " + cli + " is not properly implemented");
        }
        this.cli = cli;
        this.input = input;
        this.output = output;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Command> getCommands() {
        return commandLineInteractionInterpreter.getCommands();
    }

    public void start() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);
        showHelp();
        while (isRunning) {
            output.print(COMMAND_PROMPT);
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            List<String> words = Arrays.asList(line.split(COMMAND_SEPARATOR));
            String identifier = words.get(0);
            List<String> parameters = words.subList(1, words.size());
            Optional<Command> command = findCommand(identifier);
            if (command.isPresent()) {
                Response response = command.get().execute(parameters);
                if (response.failed()) {
                    output.println(response);
                }
            } else {
                showHelp();
            }
        }
    }

    private Optional<Command> findCommand(String identifier) {
        return getAllCommands().stream().filter(c -> c.isIdentifier(identifier)).findAny();
    }

    private Set<Command> getAllCommands() {
        Set<Command> commands = cli.getCommands();
        commands.addAll(commandLineInteractionInterpreter.getCommands());
        return commands;
    }

    public void showHelp() {
        Set<Command> commands = getAllCommands();
        output.println("help - these commands are available:");
       commands.forEach(c -> output.printf(" - %s\n", c.getIdentifier()));
    }

    public void stop() {
        isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

well honestly this class looks now far more readable - but i must confess i still carry the `Set` with this class and not the `Map` - this issue is still open and not to be mentioned as review finding. I'm still not sure if this really helps in here. maybe sleep over a night or so...

### class CommandLineInteractionInterpreter

provides the two baisc command `help` and `exit`...

```
public class CommandLineInteractionInterpreter implements CommandLineInterpreter {

    private final Set<Command> cliCommands;

    CommandLineInteractionInterpreter(CommandLineInteraction commandLineInterface) {
        super();
        cliCommands = new HashSet<>();
        cliCommands.add(new HelpCommand(commandLineInterface));
        cliCommands.add(new ExitCommand(commandLineInterface));
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Command> getCommands() {
        return cliCommands;
    }

    boolean hasCommandInCommon(CommandLineInterpreter cip) {
        return !Collections.disjoint(cip.getCommands(), getCommands());
    }

}
```

I also changed the responsibility on execution into the command - away from the interpreter. That leads to the new `CommandlineInterpreter` whose quite naked now ^^

### interface CommandLineInterpreter

```
public interface CommandLineInterpreter {
    Set<Command> getCommands();
}
```

so noetworhty, the new responsibility on execution lies on the command:

### classes ExitCommand & HelpCommand

```
public class ExitCommand extends Command<CommandLineInteraction> {

    public ExitCommand(CommandLineInteraction commandLineInteraction) {
        super(commandLineInteraction, "exit");
    }

    @Override
    public Response execute(List<String> parameter) {
        getApplication().stop();
        return Response.success();
    }
}

public class HelpCommand extends Command<CommandLineInteraction> {

    public HelpCommand(CommandLineInteraction commandLineInteraction) {
        super(commandLineInteraction, "help");
    }

    @Override
    public Response execute(List<String> parameter) {
        getApplication().showHelp();
        return Response.success();
    }
}
```

Comment: i think the `Intrepreter` should REALLY reaturn a **first-class collection** (like a `CommandMap`) - that would solve many problems, that still are in that code

Comment: i've added that - updated code is at https://github.com/martinFrank/commandLineInterface

Comment: yes yes - give `Set<Command>` a home, it's done but not visible here =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Maybe One of Us has the Wrong Idea

When I work with the code I gets confused by the `CommandLineInterpreter` and `CommandLineInteraction`, because currently a `CommandLineInteraction` **is a** `CommandLineInterpreter`. I think actually a `CommandLineInteraction` **has a** `CommandLineInterpreter`

Then I looked into the `CommandLineInterpreter`:

> ```java
> public interface CommandLineInterpreter {
>    Set<Command> getCommands();
> }
> ```

but by the name I thought to found

```java
public interface CommandLineInterpreter {
    Command interpret(String lineOfInput);
}
```

With this interface the `start` in `CommandLineInteraction` would look like

```java
public void start() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);
    showHelp();
    while (isRunning) {
        output.print(COMMAND_PROMPT);
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        Command command = interpreter.interpret(line);
        // ..
   }
}
```

---

## [Type Embedded in Name](https://blog.codinghorror.com/code-smells/)

> Avoid placing types in method names; it's not only redundant, but it forces you to change the name if the type changes.

In every place I can read `command`. Imagine you want to change the name to `task` you have to change at so many places..

> [Prefer schedule.add(course) to schedule.addCourse(course)](http://users.csc.calpoly.edu/~jdalbey/305/Lectures/SmellsToRefactorings)

---

## [Type Parameter Naming Conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

> The most commonly used type parameter names are:
>
> - E - Element (used extensively by the Java Collections Framework)
> - K - Key
> - N - Number
> - T - Type
> - V - Value
> - S,U,V etc. - 2nd, 3rd, 4th types

The class signature of `Command` do not follow the convention

> ```java
> public abstract class Command<Application>
> ```

This is not bad, but first I thought `Application` would be a class name and searched for it. If you really want to use a type parameter more than one letters, than write them all in UPPERCASE.

In your [previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/214300/java-commandline-interface-implementation) you wrote

> Any class that implements this interface can use the [`CommandLineInteraction`]. [`Application`] is the application, which implements the `CommandLineInteraction`.

This is not the case still your type parameter `Application` is not a [bounded type parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html). This means that I can create the following Commands:

```java
Command<Integer>
Command<String>
Command<CustomTypeXY>
```

If you do not want to have this behavior, you can add a *upper bound* with the key word `extends` for a class or `implements` for an interface.

```java
public abstract class Command<T extends CommandLineInteraction>
```

This means that a `T` must be a subtype or a `CommandLineInteraction`.

But if you have not the flexibility and it will only be a `CommandLineInteraction` you do not need a generic parameter at this point.

---

## Create an Instance Variable in `CommandLineInteraction`

In `CommandLineInteraction` we can find a method `getAllCommands`. This method is used in two other methods: `findCommand` and `showHelp`.
`getAllCommands` creates on each call a new `Set` with the commands of the `cli` and the commands of `commandLineInteractionInterpreter`.

Can the commands change? I think not because I find now methods, which add new commands at runtime. If this is true, create a instance variable `commands` in `CommandLineInteraction` instead of treat the method `getAllCommands` as an instance variable.

```java
public class CommandLineInteraction implements CommandLineInterpreter {

    // ..
    Set<Command> commands;

    public CommandLineInteraction(CommandLineInterpreter cli, InputStream input, PrintStream output) {
        // ..
        this.commands = getAllCommands();
    }
```

---

## What is a `CommandLineInteractionInterpreter`

> provides the two basic command help and exit

The name of `CommandLineInteractionInterpreter` is confusing and from the quote and the code you can see that it is not more than a [Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), that gives you default commands.

---

## Give `Set<Command>` a Home

A [First Class Collection](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/luontola/tdd-2009/ext/ObjectCalisthenics.pdf):

> Any class that contains a collection should contain no other member variables. Each collection gets wrapped in its own class, so now behaviors related to the collection have a home.

### Create It

```java
class CommandColletion {
    private Set<Command> values;

    public add(Command) {/* ... */}
    public union(CommandColletion values) {/* ... */}
    public contains(CommandColletion values) {/* ... */}
}
```

### Use it

```java
class CommandLineInteraction implements CommandLineInterpreter {
    // ..
    CommandCollection commands;

    CommandLineInteraction(CommandLineInterpreter cli, InputStream input, PrintStream output, CommandCollection defaults) {
        // ..
        this.commands = defaults.union(cli.getCommands());
    }
```

---

And now you can safely [change Set to `Map`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/214356/149394) :P

Comment: using a FirstClass Collection is definitely a TODO here! it's already done

Comment: my english my english - it's taking me to grave =) it's one root of my problems

Comment: how would you name a class that provides the commands?

Comment: It depends.. If you implement it based on the FactoryPattern, than something like `DefaultCommandFactory`. But if pass the defaults through the constructor you maybe do not need a Factory.

Comment: in an application that really uses the cli: the commands depend on the state of the application. if you have a look at the `SomniumGame` (https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/8246/how-can-i-play-somnium-in-real-life) you can see how the desired behaviour should look like... my somnium implementaition is under https://github.com/martinFrank/somnium (it's not reviewed yet, please don't look toooo close), but the SomniumGameCommandLineInterpreter.java shows an example on how it could work...

Comment: you can play somnuiim via cli if you want to =) - the computer AI is not so bad at all...

Comment: OK - the proper naming has been done - the CommandLineInterpreter is responsible to find the proper command and execute this command. The CommandProvider is responsible to provide the right set of commands (as class `CommandList`, not as `Set<Commands>`)